# What cable do I need for this connection

Tags: cable

I have a monitor with 2 connections labeled as output. CVBS1 and CVBS2 look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuPIq.jpg). Looking at them I'm not a hundred percent on what kind of cable I need to use.

After trying to search online I'm fairly sure its a coaxial cable with a BNC connector, but I would like to find out for sure before I order a cable.

Comment: Yes, it is a BNC connector.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Thanks! Such a strange connection to have on a monitor.

Comment: It is standard for industrial and professional video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a composite signal being output via BNC connection.  This connector is used in most professional applications as it is heavier duty and can lock to the connector so that it does not accidentally come detached.  I'm not 100% certain if this standard is compatible with RCA connectors (I started working with BNC with component video and mostly with SDI, so I'm not that familiar with composite on BNC), but it may be possible to run this in to a normal component video input (the little yellow RCA connectors on VCRs for example) via an adapter.